# click function does not work when changed to live or on

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a function that uses ajax to load content throughout one of my sites.

This works all good but at some parts because new content is brought in that has more links I need to make the click function a live click function, but when I do the ajax stops working and it just changes the page as normal ( without ajax )

here is my code

```
function ajaxLoads(){

    var $btn = $('a.ajax-btn');
    var $container = $('#load');
    var siteTitle = document.title;
    //var $artistBG = $('#artist-viewport img');

    $btn.click(function(e){

        console.log();

        e.preventDefault();
        $btn.removeClass('selected');
        //$artistBG.removeClass('top');

        var sourceTarget = $(this).data('page'),
        slideWidth = $container.width(),
        $this = $(this),
        $background = $this.data('background'),
        pageUrl=$this.attr('href'),
        pageTitle = $this.html();
        //$changeTo = $("#artist-viewport img[data-background='"+ $background +"']");

        $this.addClass('selected');
        //$changeTo.addClass('top');
        $container.animate({'right':-slideWidth}, 300, 'easeInExpo');

        $container.load(pageUrl+" "+sourceTarget, function(){

            subNav();   

            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500, 'easeInExpo', function(){
                $container.animate({'right':0}, 300, 'easeInExpo');
            });         

            var pageContent = $(this).html();

            window.history.pushState({"html":pageContent, "pageTitle": pageTitle},"", pageUrl);
            //document.title=pageTitle+" :: "+siteTitle;

        }); // end load function    

    }); // end click function   

    window.onpopstate = function(e){
        if(e.state){
            $container.css('opacity', 0).html(e.state.html).fadeTo('fast', 1);
            document.title=e.state.pageTitle+" :: "+siteTitle;
        }
    };  

}
```

I have tried changing the `$btn.click(function(e) to $btn.live('click', function(e) and to $btn.on('click', function(e)`

Comment: you can use delegate,live or on.  here is the example  http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.on` on document.

```
$(document).on('click','a.ajax-btn',function(){   });
```

Answer (score 1):

try `on`

```
 $('#load').on('click', '.ajax-btn', function(){
     ...
 });
```

live is deprecated in jquery 1.8 and removed in 1.9.. so use [`on()`](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html)

Answer (score 1):

Give your button a css class and use this

```
$(document).on("click",".yourcssclass",function(e){});
```

This will work since by  default, most events bubble up from the original event target to the document element.Though this degrades performance, a click event happens infrequently and you might use this as a fix to your problem.Then when you have time ,try to see why using delegates is not working by carefully looking on your page cycle.